# Difference between using Pointer and normal variable to call function of a base class

Tags: c++

```
// pointers to base class
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Polygon {
  protected:
    int width, height;
  public:
    void set_values (int a, int b)
      { width=a; height=b; }
};

class Rectangle: public Polygon {
  public:
    int area()
      { return width*height; }
};

class Triangle: public Polygon {
  public:
    int area()
      { return width*height/2; }
};

int main () {
  Rectangle rect;
  Triangle trgl;
  //Polygon * ppoly1 = &rect;
  //Polygon * ppoly2 = &trgl;
  //ppoly1->set_values (4,5);
  //ppoly2->set_values (4,5);
    Polygon  ppoly1 = rect;
    Polygon  ppoly2 = trgl;
    ppoly1.set_values (4,5);
    ppoly2.set_values (4,5);

  cout << rect.area() << '\n';
  cout << trgl.area() << '\n';
  return 0;
}
```

I know that commented lines( when pointer of Polygon is used to call function, its fine). Why do we need to take a pointer , why cannot we just use normal variable of type Polygon. I tried compiling, it compiles fine, but does not give the correct result. Why is it so ?.

Comment: There must be an infinity of dupes for this question.

Answer (score 4):

- You are slicing your objects when you assign a `Rectangle/Triangle` to a `Polygon`. See [What is the slicing problem in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-the-slicing-problem-in-c)
- Then you call `set_values` on (sliced) **copies**, so when you compute the area of the originals polygons, no values are actually set.
- Also your base class `Rectangle` should define a virtual destructor, and `int area()` should probably be a const pure virtual method of `Polygon`

Answer (score 0):

Because when you do

```
Polygon  ppoly1 = rect;
```

you are creating another `ppoly1` object by copying values in the `rect` object. So when you modify values of `ppoly1` actually you are not affecting the ones in `rect`, kind of when you make a photocopy of a document and scribble on the copy you are not damaging the original document. A pointer (or a reference) instead refers to the same object as before: think of the `&` operator as getting the position of the object. If you copy a pointer you are copying not the object itself but only its position, which is still the position of the original object. Think as if you write your home address to a stranger on a paper sheet: if he robs the house whose address is written in the paper sheet, your same house will be robbed.